# Which pattern to select when trying to retrieve success/failed and a object from a method?

Tags: c#, coding-style, naming-conventions, design-patterns, out

I'm discussing different implementing techniques with a colleague

Alternative A

```
User user;
if (users.TryGet(1, out user))
    Console.WriteLine(user.ToString()); 
else
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to get user..");
```

Alternative B

```
ResultSet<User> result = users.Get(1); 
if(result.OK)
    Console.WriteLine(user.ToString()); 
else
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to get user..");
```

Alternative A is similar in behaviour as `int.Parse(string, out value)` and is easy to extend and read. Adding more objects to the output when success seems easy and readable.

Alternative B seems a bit more convoluted in that there is more code on each line. But can be extended to include other information in the `ResultSet` as well as the object back. Is it more difficult to return more than one object or any ideas regarding workarounds?

Is it considered ugly/bad practice to use out parameters like that?

Comment: Why not check if the user exists before getting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Microsoft [discourages using out-parameters in public methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). A proper approach would be to throw an exception if a method fails to do the job identified by its name. In this case, if the `Get` method is unable to *Get* the data record, there should be an exception. If this situation is occuring very frequently, you could use Alternative B to improve performance a little bit in contrast to throwing exceptions every time.

As for Alternative A, method should be named `TryGet` in this case to be consistent with FCL naming conventions (`TryParse`, `TryGetValue` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with both of those methods is that you don't know why the user failed to be retrieved.

For example, if your `Get` or `TryGet` methods look like this...

```
public bool TryGet(int userId, out User user) {
    try {
        var conn = CreateDbConnection();
        var myUser = GetUser(userId, conn);
        user = myUser;
        return true;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

... then you have no way of knowing what failed while retrieving the user. Maybe the DB connection couldn't be created, maybe no user exists with the specified ID, etc.

A better method might be this:

```
public MyUser GetUser(int userId) {
    MyDbConnection conn;
    try {
        conn = CreateDbConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("The DB connection could not be created.", ex);
    }
    MyUser myUser = GetUser(userId, conn);
    if (myUser == null)
        throw new Exception("No user exists with the ID '" + userId + "'.");
    return myUser;
}
```

That way, you know what's failing, and you have a better message to log further up the chain.